# canvas drawImage img source vs canvas source

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using `drawImage` function with the same image but i got diffrent results when the source is img element vs when the source is canvas(with the same size as original image).

this is the code

```js
  async function draw(src) {

        const mainCanvas = document.getElementById("cnv");
        const ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
        let img = document.getElementById("img");

        let w = img.width;
        let h = img.height;
        if (src == "cnv") {
         
          const newCnv =      document.createElement("canvas");
          newCnv.width = w;
          newCnv.height = h;

          const newCtx = newCnv.getContext("2d");
          //just to be sure we dont touch the original image data
          newCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
          // i tested it with all function overloads and still the same
          newCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
          img = newCnv;

        }

        let destW = 850;
        const pxr = window.devicePixelRatio;
        let destH = (destW * h) / w;
        mainCanvas.style.width = destW + "px";
        mainCanvas.style.height = destH + "px";

        destW *= pxr;
        destH *= pxr;

        mainCanvas.width = destW;
        mainCanvas.height = destH;

        ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = "high";

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, destW, destH);
      }
```

```html
<img
      id="img"
      style="display: none"
      src="https://work.otzar.org/example.png"
    />
<button onclick="draw('img')">drawImage from img</button>
<button onclick="draw('cnv')">drawImage from canvas</button>
<br />
<canvas id="cnv"> </canvas>
```

i know when you use `drawImage` its does some work like for example downscale when the dest size is lower. but here the `newCnv` is the same as the original image so i dont understand why js need to do somestuff othar than just put the pixels data in the canvas.

Comment: The difference is accentuated when disabling HWA. They definitely take a different path, but not sure why the canvas bitmap has less details... (ImageBitmaps also act like that). And to be clear, this looks like a Skia thing (so mainly Chromium browsers). I'll look at this tomorrow if I get some time. For the time being I guess you can already open an issue https://crbug.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is `imageSmothingQuality = "high"`, I already faced it before, even with ImageBitmaps.
Different sources will get different results with their algo, even two JPEG <img> will have very different quality depending on the compression of the image.

You did well [opening that issue](https://crbug.com/1217601).

Note that in my tests then I had the best looking results with `imageSmothingQuality = "medium"`, which also doesn't suffer from this bug.

```js
async function draw(src) {

  const mainCanvas = document.getElementById("cnv");
  const ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
  let img = document.getElementById("img");

  let w = img.width;
  let h = img.height;
  if (src == "cnv") {

    const newCnv =      document.createElement("canvas");
    newCnv.width = w;
    newCnv.height = h;

    const newCtx = newCnv.getContext("2d");
    //just to be sure we dont touch the original image data
    newCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    // i tested it with all function overloads and still the same
    newCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
    img = newCnv;

  }

  let destW = 850;
  const pxr = window.devicePixelRatio;
  let destH = (destW * h) / w;
  mainCanvas.style.width = destW + "px";
  mainCanvas.style.height = destH + "px";

  destW *= pxr;
  destH *= pxr;

  mainCanvas.width = destW;
  mainCanvas.height = destH;

  ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = "medium";

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, destW, destH);
}
```

```html
<img
      id="img"
      style="display: none"
      src="https://work.otzar.org/example.png"
    />
<button onclick="draw('img')">drawImage from img</button>
<button onclick="draw('cnv')">drawImage from canvas</button>
<br />
<canvas id="cnv"> </canvas>
```

Comment: first of all thks. its looks like medium is better. i test it with some other images and medium still not work as with img elem. but its much more better. and i can confirm this bug not exists in firefox and safari. i sent the bug as you suggest hope they will fix it soon

Comment: Found your bug, and commented on it to make it clearer what the issue is. I hope I'll get some time to look at this myself, but I terribly lack time these days...